# HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation - MediaType produces different results

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, media-type

Using Spring MVC I have a controller with an endpoint returning a SseEmitter.

```
@GetMapping(path = "/accept/{amount}", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    @ApiResponses({
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "OK"),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "409", description = "BUSY", content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = MyErrorClass.class))),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "UNEXPECTED_ERROR", content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = MyErrorClass.class)))
    })
    public SseEmitter accept(@Parameter(description = "Amount to accept") @PathVariable double amount) throws MyException {
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter();
        myService.accept(amount);
        service.execute(() -> {
            while(myService.inAcceptanceState()) {
                try {
                    emitter.send(myService.getCurrentAmount());
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException | IOException ex) {
                    emitter.completeWithError(ex);
                }
            }
            try {
                emitter.send(myService.getCurrentAmount());
                emitter.complete();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                emitter.completeWithError(e);
            }
        });
        service.shutdown();
        return emitter;
    }
```

In the case of the above code the accept() method is expected to throw a 400 error when it is called a second time before the first call completes. As of now I'm getting the following:

```
2020-09-03 15:22:14.105  WARN 480 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Failure in @ExceptionHandler com.mydomain.common.ExceptionController#handleMyException(Exception)

org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
```

This does not crash my springboot service, but the call doesn't terminate so is causing obvious issue. I have noticed it works wonderfully if I change to `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_STREAM_VALUE`. It returns exception and error message associated with that exception as I would expect, but we need to be using TEXT_STREAM for SseEmitter and our consumers are expecting this type of return.  From my (limited) understanding Spring has some magic HttpConversion happening with response bodies, so what do I need to do in order to return an exception using `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_STREAM_VALUE`? Do I need to write my own response converter, however that might look...?

Comment: It seems this issue is similar to what I'm encountering, but no solution: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/23821
I do imagine @ExceptionHandler can be utilized, but not sure if it is that straightforward

Answer (score 0):

You are not terminating your executor properly. A call to shutdown does not do what you might expect it to do. An example from the javadoc of ExecutorService.

```
 void shutdownAndAwaitTermination(ExecutorService pool) {
   pool.shutdown(); // Disable new tasks from being submitted
   try {
     // Wait a while for existing tasks to terminate
     if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
       pool.shutdownNow(); // Cancel currently executing tasks
       // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled
       if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
           System.err.println("Pool did not terminate");
     }
   } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
     // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
     pool.shutdownNow();
     // Preserve interrupt status
     Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
   }
 }
```

In general a cachedThread pool should be shared resources and should not be initialized within a endpoint. The point of a cachedThreadPool is to take advantage of thread reuse and to avoid runaway creation of threads.  If you really need a single thread use [newSingleThreadExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor())

I don't actually understand why you are using an executor at all here.  It does not seem like its adding any value. You are just blocking your request handler thread to execute code in a different thread when it could have just executed in the original thread.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I think some of this was a bad case of copy pasta, though not an answer for my actual issue.